# Not able to insert data in MSSQL using r2dbc (non spring)

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, project-reactor, r2dbc

I am new to r2dbc. I am trying to connect to MSSQL DB using R2DBC (non spring project) with reactor. It is not establishing the connection and also the data is not getting inserted into the table. I have tried by giving wrong table name as well, but there is no exception for it.

```
public Flux<MssqlResult> writetoDB() {
        return createDBConnection().create()
                .flatMapMany(c -> c.createStatement("INSERT INTO person (id, first_name, last_name) VALUES(@id, @firstname, @lastname)")
                        .bind("id", 1)
                        .bind("firstname", "Walter")
                        .bind("lastname", "White")
                        .execute()
                        .doFinally((st) -> c.close()))
                .log();
    }

private MssqlConnectionFactory createDBConnection() {
        MssqlConnectionConfiguration configuration = MssqlConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                .host("sample-host").username("testuser")
                .password("testuser1").database("testDB").preferCursoredExecution(true).build();
        MssqlConnectionFactory factory = new MssqlConnectionFactory(configuration);
        return factory;
    }
```

Kindly suggest what I am missing here.

Comment: If you don't subscribe to the `Flux` that is being returned, nothing will happen.

Comment: It is been subscribed by the method which invokes writetoDB method

Comment: If it's not establishing the connection, that's where you should start - you've no hope of inserting stuff into the database without that. Any logs or exceptions you can share about why the connection isn't established?

Comment: @MichaelBerry There is no error which is really strange
I am using reactor version : 3.4.3 (tried with 3.4.6 and 3.4.7)
r2dbc-mssql version:  0.9.0.M1

Comment: I have added code which can be tested individually below

Comment: Are @sen and "@pri" the same person writing comments? If so, why are you using both accounts - that only adds confusion. An "answer" that is merely a correction or elaboration to the original question is also confusing.

Comment: if you're doing that subscription in a test, it is likely that the r2dbc driver performs its operations on a dedicated thread. since `subscribe` is non-blocking, in the context of a test the execution would immediately stop. use `reactor-test`'s `StepVerifier` rather than direct subscribe to assert the results.